# Creating a labeled tetrahedron with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, 3d

I am wanting to draw a tetrahedron with labeled points on each corner. I attempted to edit the example of a cone that I found here: [A cone with tikzpicture](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/cone/)
I have made it look partially like a tetrahedron but have not been able to get it right (let alone labeled points). This is what I’ve got so far:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
 \def\RI{2}
 \def\RII{1.25}

 \draw[] (\RI,0)
   \foreach \x in {0,240} { --  (\x:\RI) node at (\x:\RI) (R1-\x) {} };
 \draw[dashed,thick] (R1-0.center)
   \foreach \x in {120} { --  (\x:\RI) node at (\x:\RI) (R1-\x) {} };


 \begin{scope}[yshift=2cm]
 \draw[thick,fill=gray!30,opacity=0.2] (\RII,0)
   \foreach \x in {0,120,240,360}
     { --  (\x:\RII) node at (\x:\RII) (R2-\x) {}};
 \end{scope}

 \foreach \x in {0,240} { \draw (R1-\x.center)--(R2-\x.center); };
 \foreach \x in {120} { \draw[dashed] (R1-\x.center)--(R2-\x.center); };
 \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

and this is what it compiles to give:

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With help from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Formulas_for_a_regular_tetrahedron) and `TikZ`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line join = round, line cap = round]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/sqrt(2)};
\coordinate [label=right:A] (A) at (2,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=left:B] (B) at (-2,0,-2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=above:C] (C) at (0,2,2*\factor);
\coordinate [label=below:D] (D) at (0,-2,2*\factor);

\draw[->] (0,0) -- (3,0,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,3,0) node[above] {$y$};
\draw[->] (0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[below left] {$z$};
\foreach \i in {A,B,C,D}
    \draw[dashed] (0,0)--(\i);
\draw[-, fill=red!30, opacity=.5] (A)--(D)--(B)--cycle;
\draw[-, fill=green!30, opacity=.5] (A) --(D)--(C)--cycle;
\draw[-, fill=purple!30, opacity=.5] (B)--(D)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Tetahedron]

Comment: Does anyone know which modifiers add nodes at the points A,B,C,D?

Comment: @user1922184 If your question means how letters A, B, C and D are written, the answer is `label:right:A` in coordinate options. If your question is not this, please rephrase it.

Comment: I was able to figure out the code for moving the label around, but really appreciate it. I however am having trouble finding looking for the code to put points at the corners so one at each A,B,C, and D. For example, the answer that "Don Joe" gave below has the black nodes but I am unsure how to get "\draw[fill=black] (P\i) circle (0.15em)" to work.

Comment: @user1922184: As Dohn Joe did it, draw them over each coordinate: `\foreach \i in {A, B, C, D}
\fill[black] (\i) circle(1pt);` Depending where you include these lines, the circles will be (or not) covered with tetrahedron faces.

Comment: I am using your tetrahedron in some solutions I am creating for myself on github. Is there any way you want to be credited or cited? [github repo](https://github.com/dwsmith1983/Abstract-D-F-Solutions)

Comment: @dustin. Thank you for your interest in this answer. Regarding credits and attributions I think this topic is covered in section 3 from [Stack Exchange Network Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal)

Answer (score 7):

this is a hexahedral, but maybe this gives you a starting point.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.65cm, y=0.65cm]

% Specify the coordinates
\coordinate (P0) at (0.0, 0.0); % 0
\coordinate (P1) at (10.0, 0.0); % 1
\coordinate (P2) at (13.0, 2.50); % 2
\coordinate (P3) at (3.0, 2.50); % 3

\coordinate (P4) at (0.0, 6.0); % 4
\coordinate (P5) at (10.0, 6.0); % 5
\coordinate (P6) at (14.0, 8.50); % 6
\coordinate (P7) at (3.0, 8.50); % 7


% draw and number the edges
\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P0) -- (P1);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P0)!0.5!(P1)$) {$0 \,\rightarrow$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P2);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P1)!0.55!(P2)$) {$\overset{\nearrow}{5}$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P0) -- (P4);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P0)!0.5!(P4)$) {$\overset{\uparrow}{8}$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P4) -- (P5);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P4)!0.5!(P5)$) {$3 \,\rightarrow$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P4) -- (P7);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P4)!0.5!(P7)$) {$\overset{\nearrow}{7}$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P5) -- (P6);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P5)!0.5!(P6)$)   {$\overset{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-8}{$\nearrow$}}}{6}$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P7) -- (P6);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P7)!0.5!(P6)$) {$2 \,\rightarrow$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P1) -- (P5);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P1)!0.6!(P5)$) {$\overset{\uparrow}{9}$};

\draw[line width=0.5pt] (P2) to[out=90,in=-120] (P6);
\node[fill=white,anchor=east] (c) at ($(P2)!0.5!(P6)$)     {$\overset{\text{\rotatebox[origin=c]{-10}{$\uparrow$}}}{10}$};

\draw[dashed, line width=0.5pt] (P3) -- (P0);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P0)!0.65!(P3)$) {$\overset{\nearrow}{4}$};

\draw[dashed, line width=0.5pt] (P3) -- (P2);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P3)!0.5!(P2)$) {$1 \,\rightarrow$};

\draw[dashed, line width=0.5pt] (P3) -- (P7);
\node[fill=white] (c) at ($(P3)!0.35!(P7)$) {$\overset{\uparrow}{11}$};

% numbering the nodes
\foreach \i in {2,3,6,7}
{
    \draw[fill=black] (P\i) circle (0.15em)
    node[above right,blue,font=\bfseries] {\Large \i};
}
\foreach \i in {0,1,4,5}
{
    \draw[fill=black] (P\i) circle (0.15em)
    node[below left,blue,font=\bfseries] {\Large \i};
}

% coordinate system
\node (x) at ($(P0)!0.15!(P1)$) {};
\node (y) at ($(P0)!0.45!(P3)$) {};
\node (z) at ($(P0)!0.35!(P4)$) {};

\draw[-latex,thick] (P0) to (x) node [below] {$x$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (P0) to (y) node [below] {$y$};
\draw[-latex,thick] (P0) to (z) node [right] {$z$};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: A block]

The points are labelled, so this will be rather easy to modify. Have fun. I created this image from some example from [TeXample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/).

The following code creates the block as a standalone image. Works with `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\input{block.tikz}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Run with `xelatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=40 10 10 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=30}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(3,3)
\psSolid[object=tetrahedron,r=3,action=draw*,name=T,num=1 2 3]% without 0
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 0,text=Top,pos=uc]% Point T0 (top)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How about this one.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw[thick, fill=gray] (0,1.5) -- (1.2,0.4) -- (0,-1) -- (0,1.5) -- (-1.6,-0.1) -- (0,-1);
\draw[thick, dashed] (1.1,0.4) -- (-1.5,-0.1) ;

\draw[thick, red] (-0.5132,0.247) -- (-2.1795,0.0633) ;
\draw[thick, red, dashed] (1.839,0.4928) -- (-0.396,0.247) ;

\fill (-1.8,-0.4) circle (0pt) node[above] {4};
\fill (0,-1.5) circle (0pt) node[above] {3};
\fill (1.3,0.4) circle (0pt) node[above] {2};
\fill (0,1.6) circle (0pt) node[above] {1};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]