# To draw a a labeled tetrahedron

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, pstricks

How to write the LaTex code of the tetrahedron (avoiding the arrow) given in the figure below:[image]

Comment: Welcome, do you you already have some code and can't get the rest done or do you want the complete code?

Comment: Thank you very much for replying.  I need the complete code.

Comment: The tags changed from `TikZ` to `PSTricks`.

Comment: Closely related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174317/creating-a-labeled-tetrahedron-with-tikzpicture

Comment: I added back the `tikz-pgf` tag, since the OP didn't mention a desired method to obtain the sketch (not in the title, nor in the text), so any approach is good, the `PSTricks` one as well as the `TikZ` one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code makes use of `tikz` package.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (a) at (4,2.5);
    \coordinate (b) at (3,.8);
    \coordinate (c) at (5,0);
    \coordinate (d) at (5.3,1.2);
    \coordinate (e) at (0,0);

    \draw[thick, fill=black!10] (a) -- (b) -- (e) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, fill=black!20] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- (d) -- cycle;
    \draw[thick, fill=black!30] (b) -- (c) -- (e) -- cycle;
    \draw[very thick] (a) -- (c);
    \draw[thick, dash dot dot] (b) -- (d);

    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick] (a) circle (3pt) node[black, above right] {$a$};
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick] (b) circle (3pt) node[black, above left] {$b$};
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick] (c) circle (3pt) node[black, below right] {$c$};
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick] (d) circle (3pt) node[black, above right] {$d$};
    \fill[black!20, draw=black, thick] (e) circle (3pt) node[black, below left] {$e$};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image]

You can further play with positions and `anchor`s of `node`s to get exactly the alignment you want for labels.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I can not set figure number below this diagram.

Comment: If you are talking about "Figure 3: In this sketch a nice tetrahedron is depicted", that is the caption, you should simply put the `tikzpicture` environment inside a `figure` environment and add a `caption` after it (still inside the `figure` env).

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}
\psset{viewpoint=40 -10 10 rtp2xyz,lightsrc=viewpoint,Decran=30}
\begin{pspicture}[solidmemory](-2,-2)(3,3)
\psSolid[object=tetrahedron,r=3,action=draw*,name=T]% without 0
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 0,text=d,pos=uc]% Point T0 %(top)
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 1,text=c,pos=cl]% Point T1
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 2,text=b,pos=dc]% Point T1
\psSolid[object=point,definition=solidgetsommet,args=T 3,text=a,pos=cr]% Point T1
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Herbert, I have compiled with Latex and PDF does not appear the drawing. Why? (I use TXCenter).

Comment: you have to use `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

Comment: Herbert, I was only able to compile to DVI Latex. It was perfect.

Comment: I will create your figure with `pstplus` at the link http://www.xm1math.net/pstplus/index.html.